# How to call each method in some array with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have this code

```
var fields = [
    'ile_sprzedal', 'ile_zarobil', 'srednia_kwota', 'konwersja', 'punkty'
];
fields.each(function(i, v){
    var sum = sum_ + v;
        sum = 0;
    var it = it_ + v;
        it = 0;
});
```

and this error: `TypeError: Object [object Array] has no method 'each'`. And the question is - How to call each method on some array?

Comment: the method is `forEach(function(v, i){})`

Comment: what is the purpose of sum and it as you are resetting it as soon after calculating it

Comment: Yes, forEach is the right one; You still can take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-in-an-array-how-to-do-that-in-javascript

Comment: if it's jquery, it would be `$.each(fields, function(i, v) {...`

Comment: `$.each(fields, func(){});` try with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Array does not have a each() method, it has [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) like - [Supported by IE>=9](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Browser_compatibility)

```
var fields = [
    'ile_sprzedal', 'ile_zarobil', 'srednia_kwota', 'konwersja', 'punkty'];
fields.forEach(function (v, i) {
    var sum = sum_ + v;
    sum = 0;
    var it = it_ + v;
    it = 0;
});
```

Or jQuery has a [$.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) method - cross browser

```
var fields = [
    'ile_sprzedal', 'ile_zarobil', 'srednia_kwota', 'konwersja', 'punkty'];
$.each(fields, function (i, v) {
    var sum = sum_ + v;
    sum = 0;
    var it = it_ + v;
    it = 0;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery:

```
$.each(fields, function(index, item){
    /* further processing */
});
```

Comment: As @A.Wolff points out, you shouldn't use [`$(selector).each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) for this; instead [`$.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) should be used if you are iterating over an array or object. They have similar names and can easily be confused, but they are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

Well fields is just a plain array.  The `$().each()` (https://api.jquery.com/each/) call is restricted for jQuery objects.  So you need to either wrap fields in a jQuery object (`$(fields).each`) or just use the $.each call: `$.each(fields, function(i, v)` (https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/).